# Efficiently Integrate Patch of NuGet Package

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

Our small, distributed team uses a NuGet package in a project.  That package has a bug in the current release.  Unfortunately the package does not [publish debug symbols and source](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-symbol-package), so I grabbed & built the latest source, removed the project via NuGet and added a (temporary) reference to the project I just built locally.

Turns out, the issue is fixed in the latest code base.

This particular project only seems to release updates on NuGet every 6 months or so.

Until that next release, our team needs to use the code version where the bug is fixed.

One option certainly is to check the source code into our source code repository and keep the project reference (rather than a NuGet reference), essentially treating it as an internal utility project.

That feels "old school" though.

Is there a better way to manage this situation, using the NuGet infrastructure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create your own NuGet package with the updated code. Then add a new Local Package source (just create a file share and place the .nupkg file there). Move the local package source up higher in priority than the official one so NuGet will use your package before looking online.

In fact I recommend copying all NuGet packages to a local repository, especially if you use package restore. This way you are not dependent on nuget.org to be up all the time (there have been several instances of downtime).

The one drawback is that when an updated package is finally published to nuget.org, Update-Package will not pick up the new one unless you specify the package source.

Anyway this will allow you to continue to use NuGet while waiting for your updated package.

Comment: Our team is distributed (without a shared file server).  Is it possible (and fairly straightforward) to use a mechanism other than file share for a local package?

Comment: You can try myget.org. They have a free plan to host your NuGet packages. You can also host your own NuGet gallery. https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery